# Android touch - to - focus

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to make a custom camera application to let the users touch the screen to focus rather to take the picture. Is there any related API in Android to support ?

```
public void takePhoto(File photoFile, String workerName, int width, int height,   int        quality) {
if (getAutoFocusStatus()){
    camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    }); 
}else{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
}

this.photoFile = photoFile;
this.workerName = workerName;
this.imageOutputWidth = width;
this.imageOutputHeight = height;
}

public void takePhoto(File photoFile, int width, int height, int quality) {
takePhoto(photoFile, null, width, height, quality);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to take photos then don't call takepicture() from autofocuscallback.
Also if you want to focus on the point where the user touched the screen you can use setFocusAreas() to set the focusareas.